# Python serial readline function output

Tags: python, readline

I cannot convert serial readline function to output as int.

```py
import serial

armSerial = serial.Serial()
armSerial.baudrate = 115200
armSerial.port = 'COM11'
armSerial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
armSerial.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
armSerial.open()

for i in range(10000):
    line = armSerial.readline()
    decoded_bytes = str((line.decode("utf-8"))[1:-1])
    data = int(decoded_bytes)
    print(decoded_bytes)

armSerial.close()
```

I am getting the error:

> data = int(decoded_bytes)
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with
>   base 10: '94\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n'

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes

Comment: int.from_bytes(line, byteorder='big', signed=True)  returns numbers in 8 digits but my numbers are with the sign in 3 digits.

Comment: What number do you expect from `'94\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\'`?

Comment: the problem was with my C++ code in microcontroller. i didn't send it correctly. thank you for helping.